# How to access properties from view after it loaded

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Storyboard:

[image: Storyboard]

Constraints:

[image]

Result:

[image]

I'm trying to understand autolayout and how I can use it inside a container.

I got a default ViewController that was made for me when I opened the Storyboard. I put a View Container inside there. And then I added a loose (not connected to anything) ViewController. I want the content inside the new ViewController to be put in the container.

So the added ViewController which will be put inside the Container consists of three labels where I am using autolayout.

Clicking on the black bar for the Container View Controller in the Storyboard I go to Identity Inspector and set the Custom Class to "ContainerViewController". Then I set the Storyboard ID to "ChildController" for the loose View Controller.

Then I override `viewDidLoad` in `ContainerViewController.m`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIViewController *child = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChildController"];
    [self addChildViewController:child];
    [self.view addSubview:child.view];

}
```

Why won't the constraints for the autolayout work when put in a container? I hoped they would, so I could take this further to a UIPageViewController.

**EDIT:**

So it seems to be the frame size. I need to do something like this before adding it as sub view:

```
child.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 265, 370);
```

Now I created an outlet for the Container in `ViewController.h`.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *container;
```

But.. From ContainerViewController, how can I ask presenting view controller (ViewController) of this property when it's not set yet?

```
ViewController *parent = (ViewController*)self.presentingViewController;
UIView *container = parent.container;

NSLog(@"ParentView Container Width: %f, Height: %f", container.frame.size.width, container.frame.size.height);
```

It just gave me zero width and height, because the view hasn't loaded yet. Later on when it loads, I get the actual values..

```
NSLog(@"View Controller Container. Width: %f, Height: %f", self.container.frame.size.width, self.container.frame.size.height);
```

**The question:** How can I access properties of presentingViewController when they are ready/loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when adding a child view controller you should set its view frame like this

```
UIViewController *child = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChildController"];
[self addChildViewController:child];
[self.view addSubview:child.view];

//set the view frame
child.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
```

So the child view controller will resize its view frame and layout contraints will do their homework ;)

**EDIT**

put the code in `-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews` like this:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    UIViewController *child = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChildController"];
    [self addChildViewController:child];
    [self.view addSubview:child.view];

    //set the view frame
    child.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
}
```

Comment: NSLog(@"Bounds %f", self.view.bounds.size.height) is 480. But the container is smaller than that, look at the image for the Storyboard, first ViewController.

Comment: My guess is that because boounds are not set yet in veiwDidLoad. Try to use viewWillLayoutSubviews instead.

Comment: put above code in `-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead of `-(void)viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 0):

Just try to set frame in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` for view Controller